# Resetting values for some columns in a large table

Tags: sql-server

I have a very large table (10 millions of rows and 15 columns). Now I have a list of data to update all values in 2 columns (5 and 13). The values for each rows in these 2 columns are different.

Currently I've to write 10 million lines like this

```
UPDATE table SET col5 = value1 WHERE RowNumber = 1
UPDATE table SET col5 = value2 WHERE RowNumber = 2
UPDATE table SET col5 = value3 WHERE RowNumber = 3
...
UPDATE table SET col5 = value10000000 WHERE RowNumber = 10000000
```

for `column5`.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Can't you write some code to take your list, convert it to SQL and run them automatically without needing manual assistance?

Comment: From where you are getting the values ? I mean for `RowNumber = 1` you are updating `col5 = value1` how you are getting the `value1`, Is it from some other table ?

Comment: Currently I have a excel sheet of them, so I input them using my hands. They are not from other table. So I need a way to accept the input and accept rownumber. I notice sometimes the required rows are not repeated like 1,2,3,4,5 etc but 1,5,9,10,20....

Comment: @DaWei Import the excel into database and update using join